# For loop adds elements to array succesfully but returns empty array after

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, for-loop

So this bit of code runs successfully and adds the elements to the array which is confirmed by logging them to the console but after, when I return the array, it is returned empty. I have been banging my head against the wall with this all morning.

```
details.getDetails = function(idSet, pageNum) {
      var page = idSet[pageNum],
          placeDetails = [],
          i;

      for(i=0; i<page.length; i++){
        ngGPlacesAPI.placeDetails({placeId: page[i]})
          .then(function(data){
            response = data;
            placeDetails.push(response);
            console.log(placeDetails) //This shows the loop running and the array being populated
          })
      }
      return placeDetails;
      console.log(placeDetails) //This returns empty array 
    };
```

I did think the problem might have to do with asynchronous data as Rayon mentioned and I tried to return a promise but I'm not sure I am doing it right. Here is the code I tried.

```
.factory('details', function(ngGPlacesAPI, $q){
    var response,
        details = {};

 details.getDetails = function(idSet, pageNum) {
      var page = idSet[pageNum],
          deferred = $q.defer,
          placeDetails = [],
          i;

      for(i=0; i<page.length; i++){
        ngGPlacesAPI.placeDetails({placeId: page[i]})
          .then(function(data){
            response = data;
            placeDetails.push(response);
          })
      }
      deferred.resolve(placeDetails);
      console.log(deferred.promise);
      return deferred.promise;
    };

    // Return Details Object
    return details;
  });
```

Comment: You are dealing with `asynchronous` events..

Comment: Why the down vote? I know I'm doing something wrong that is why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the .placeDetails immediately returns and so the the for loop is long finished before you actually retrieved some data. That's why using a Promise here doesn't really help you since the resolve call will be called almost immediately.

I would suggest looking into $q.all to wait before all your calls to placeDetails have been finished before resolving your promise.

Something like this (untested) code should work for you. It might need some changes, but it should give you an idea.

```
details.getDetails = function(idSet, pageNum) {
      var page = idSet[pageNum],
          placeDetails = [],
          mainDeferred = $q.defer(),
          promises = [];

      for(var i=0; i<page.length; i++){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        ngGPlacesAPI.placeDetails({placeId: page[i]})
          .then(function(data){
            placeDetails.push(data);
            deferred.resolve();
          });
        promises.push(deferred.promise);
      }
    $q.all(promises).then(function() {
       mainDeferred.resolve(placeDetails); 
    });
    return mainDeferred;
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I ran the code above and it creates the array of promises and then returns the one promise but when I try to use it in the controller with this code `details.getDetails(page, pageNum).then(function(response){
      vm.restaurants = response;
      console.log(vm.restaurants);
    });` I don't get anything logged to the console but I also don't get any errors.

Comment: @GrantJordan As i've said; the code that I gave you was to give you a general idea and not the solution on a silver platter :-) You might need to do some debugging to get things to work. For example; don't use the global array but pass the result of the `.placeDetails()` in the resolve function and then add the values of all the results in the `$q.all()`.

You can check https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall for more information about the all() function.

Comment: Thank you so much for getting me on the right track. With a little tweaking I got everything running.